# Ionic serve command resets the index.html page

Tags: ionic-framework

I've recently started developing in Ionic, and I find that once I've made changes to the index.html file and run it (ionic serve), it resets the index.html file.

I think I might be missing a step somewhere, any ideas?

Found the error. I was editing the file in the www folder and not the one in the src folder. Once I updated the index.html file in the src folder, the changes appear in the file in the www folder.

However, I find that when I update the controllers in the src/js folder, they are not updated in the www/js folder, so I have to make updates to the files in the www/js folder.

Not really sure of what's going on.

Comment: May be you are editing the wrong file/generated one

Comment: @Mr_Perfect you're right, I just found out the error. I was changing in the index file in the www folder and not the one in the src folder. It's working now.

Comment: @user1634781 You should mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

**src** folder is true development folder.

When ionic builds the app for you it automatically copies all the required files from **src/** to **www/**.

If its not happening there might be something wrong with project, try removing and adding platform again.